How to create distorted patterns in Illustrator?
I need to make this kind of images in vector with different patterns, any idea how to do it?
(attached examples)


I would do as Scott suggests. There are also other tools such as the Bloat tool which could be used for the bottom example.  For anything more complex, you could also use actual 3D software to distort shapes, render a raster image, bring it into Illustrator and auto trace it.

I would not refer to this as "3D", nor any "optical illusion". It's merely a pattern which has been distorted.
Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp will do a lot on a simple pattern of circles.

